# Unable to use for-loop on model list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view, cshtml file I have a script part.

There is a model list on this view and I want to iterate through the items in that model list in a JavaScript `function` but I cannot use `for` loop in order to iterate the list.

It says "The name `i` does not exist in the current context".

If I write `@Html.Raw(Model[0].DataName);` it is working fine and `countModel` comes correctly. How can I use that in a `for` loop?

Here is the code:

```
 var countModel = @(Model.Count);

 for (var i = 0; i < countModel; i++) {
     var dt = @Html.Raw(Model[i].DataName);
     ...
 }
```

Comment: @BG101

i have tried using that before too. but i have to put model[i].DataName into Html.Raw and i cannot do this of course.
var model = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

Comment: @Dane Santiago
also i cannot use foreach. if i do i cannot use the array defined outside that scope or can't define an array within that scope.

Comment: you dont need `Html.Raw` around `model[i].DataName` as `model` is now a javascript object.

Comment: this is just a string model[i].DataName. it is actually datatable's name. in the following part if i use this like var dt = model[i].DataName it is accepted as a string and when i want  to reach data in that datatable like dt[0] of course i can't. but when define dt as var dt = Html.Raw(Model[0].DataName) it is as datatable and i can reach the data i want by typing dt[0] so i have to use it in html.raw

Comment: make sure you are outside of any `@{  }` blocks. you need to be inside `<script> ... </script>` for it to be javascript. if it is coming up as a string, then it is being parsed as C#.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `i` is a variable in javascript, where you are trying to use it in C#.

You need to convert your `Model` to a Javascript object, then iterate over that.

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++)
{
    var dt = model[i].DataName;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to leverage the Model.Count without having to assign it to the variable count model by using the foreach loop. Should look something like this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Count)
{
 //You Code Here
}
```